# getting no class found while running applet also no out put

Tags: java, xml, applet

I am having one java file which will read the xml and print the count which access the other java file as a package. but when i run it i am getting no class found. here is complete code.

ticket.java

package com.asn.model;

public class ticket {

```
private String team;
private String imp;

public ticket(String team, String imp) {

    super();

    this.team = team;


    this.imp = imp;
}

public String getteam() {
    return team;
}

public void setteam(String team) {

    this.team = team;
}

public String getimp() {
    return imp;
}

public void setimp(String imp) {
    this.imp = imp;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((team == null) ? 0 : team.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((imp == null) ? 0 : imp.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ticket other = (ticket) obj;
    if (team == null) {
        if (other.team != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!team.equals(other.team))
        return false;
    if (imp == null) {
        if (other.imp != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!imp.equals(other.imp))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("incident [team=");
    builder.append(team);
    builder.append(", imp=");
    builder.append(imp);
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

Another java file is ticket count java

```
    package com.asn.model;


 import com.asn.model.ticket;

 public class ticketcount extends applet {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ticket> ticketList = new ArrayList<ticket>();
    try {

        String Path = "C:\\Users\\";

        File fXmlFile = new File(Path + "\\ticket.xml");

        // File fXmlFile = new File(App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("C:\\Users\// \

        //   \tickets.xml").getFile());
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList ticketNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ticket");


        for (int temp = 0; temp < ticketNodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node varNode = ticketNodeList.item(temp);

            if (varNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) varNode;

                NodeList teamList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("team");
                NodeList varsionList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("imp");

                Node teamNode = teamList.item(0);
                Node impNode = varsionList.item(0);

                if (teamNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && impNode.getNodeType() ==

                        Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element teamElement = (Element) teamNode;
                    Element impElement = (Element) impNode;
                    ticket ticket = new ticket(teamElement.getTextContent(),

                            impElement.getTextContent());
                    ticketList.add(ticket);
                }
            }
            String content1 =

                    "<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><TABLE><tr><td>Chain</td><td><b>Priority</b></td<td></td><td>count</td><

                            / tr > ";
            String content = "";
            File file = new File(Path + "\\result1.html");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<ticket, Integer> count = new HashMap<ticket, Integer>();
    for (ticket c : ticketList)
        if (!count.containsKey(c))
            count.put(c, Collections.frequency(ticketList, c));

    List<String> imps = getimps(count);
    List<String> teams = getteams(count);

    StringBuilder heading = new StringBuilder("ticket \t| ");
    for (String s : imps) {
        heading.append(s);
        heading.append("\t| ");
    }

    System.out.println(heading);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");


    for (String m : teams) {
        System.out.println(m + "\t| " + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count));
        content = content + "<tr><td>" + m + "</td><td>" + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count) + "</td></tr>";
    }
    bw.write(content1 + content + "</TABLE></HTML>");
    bw.close();

    Runtime rTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String url = Path + "result.html";
    //String url = "C:\\Users\\a561922\\Desktop\\TEST.html";//"D:/hi.html";
    String browser = "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe ";
    File htmlFile = new File(url);
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());

    //   Process pc = rTime.exec(browser + url);
    //    pc.waitFor();

    //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\a561922\\Desktop\\TEST.html");
}


private static List<String> getteams(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
    List<String> teams = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
        if (!teams.contains(ent.getKey().getteam()))
            teams.add(ent.getKey().getteam());
    return teams;
}


private static String getNumOfteams(String team, List<String> imps, Map<ticket, Integer>

        count) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


    for (String v : imps) {
        Integer cnt = count.get(new ticket(team, v));
        if (cnt == null) {
            cnt = 0;
        }
        builder.append(cnt + "\t");
    }


    return builder.toString();
}


private static List<String> getimps(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
    List<String> imps = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
        if (!imps.contains(ent.getKey().getimp()))
            imps.add(ent.getKey().getimp());
    return imps;
}
```

}

Comment: i have compiled the program from folder Program as javac *.java

Comment: these files are placed under folder program/com/asn/model